# Text goes out of bounds for phones with a smaller width size

Tags: java, android, layout, textview, text-size

I have a set of codes that fit all phones with a width of 1080 or bigger, however for phones with 720 widths my last TextView with textSize of 20dp with the text "Price" goes halfway out of bound the phone width. So basically, for phones with a width of 1080 or bigger, I want to keep my textSize of 20dp, since it fits those phones, but for phones with a width of 720 I want to decrease the textSize of it. How would I do that?

**Need this to work for android 5.0 and up**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="500dp"
android:background="#00FFFFFF"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
android:layout_width="409dp"
android:layout_height="300dp"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">                

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="44dp"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="268dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="268dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="96dp"
            android:onClick="onButtonClick"
            android:text="Go"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/Name1"
            android:layout_width="67dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="85dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Symbol"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            android:layout_width="109dp"
            android:layout_height="37dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="76dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="76dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="92dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/Price1"
            android:layout_width="72dp"
            android:layout_height="51dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="192dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="192dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="84dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Amount"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="31dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="324dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="324dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:text="Price"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Start by adding `end` constraints. Then, consider using auto-sizing: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview.

Comment: @CommonsWare That's android 8.0 or higher tho.

Comment: No, with `appcompat` auto-size works on older devices as well. Use `app:` instead of `android:` for the attribute namespace prefix, though.

Comment: @CommonsWare Can you add a few codes to my <textView> and submit it as an answer so I can see how exactly it is done? I will upvote and accept answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've gone through your layout and tried to improve it how I would do a layout like this. You're using `ConstraintLayout` so you want to align views in relation to each other. For example, you can align your price to the far right, and have it expand to the left, and push other views left.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00FFFFFF"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/Name1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:hint="Symbol"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="44dp"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:onClick="onButtonClick"
            android:text="Go"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/text1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:minWidth="120dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/Name1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/Price1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:hint="Amount"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button1"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/spinner1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="Price"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```